# Simple way to replace string in JavaScript with wildcards

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Is there a simple way to replace something in a string in javascript with a wildcard but also use the wildcard in the resulting string:

So for example I have the String:

```
loop(10)
{
   // do something
}
```

and I want to replace the "loop" with a real for loop like this:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   // do something
}
```

but to do this with a simple `.replace` I would need a wildcard. Obviously there is a solution to this problem but it seems very costly to me.

Comment: u want to learn [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: You'll need to specify what you want exactly. It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Do you want to do this in a text editor or in code?

Comment: sry i found out myself: This is the solution that works for me: .replace(/loop((.*))/,"for(i=0;i<" + "$1" + ";i++)");

Comment: @manzet Please post your answer in the answers and mark it correct if you have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
.replace(/loop((.*))/,"for(i=0;i<" + "$1" + ";i++)");
```

Comment: You need to escape the literal parentheses.

Comment: You don't need the concatenations in the replacement part. Just write `"for(i=0;i< $1;i++)"`